# Separate setups of Sublime 3

Tags: macos, user-profiles, sublime-text-3

Is it possible to have two or more different setups of Sublime Text 3?

What I mean by that is:

- I would like to have one Sublime with my Python settings.
  This includes the packages, theme, keyboard shortcuts, etc.
- and a second for the development with React, again different theme, packages...

I just don't want them mixed up.

Answer (score 0):

I have two on the go right now. I have one installed in my Dropbox directory and one on my localhost. I have shortcuts to both in my start menu.

You can maintain as many different installations as you like by using the portable versions that are available on the download page.

Addition:
You may be interested in projects and workspaces. I haven't used them, but they may suit your needs. If you specify a setting in the project file it'll override the default. https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/projects.html

Comment: thought there is a smarter way of doing it... but thanks!